# Converting a list of Dictionaries to dataframe about a key

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

Is there a way to convert a list of dictionaries to a pandas dataframe for a single dictionary key?

Say, for sample_list = `[{1:2.1, 2:4.5, 5:6.4}, {1:4.3, 2:5.4, 5:1}, {1:0.07, 2:9.5, 5:7.1}]`
The data frame would be

```
 2 
---
4.5 
5.4  
9.5
```

where 2 is the column name.

**EDIT:**

Is there a way to rename the column and have something like

```
two
---
4.5 
5.4  
9.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify `columns=` parameter when creating the dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(sample_list, columns=[2])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     2
0  4.5
1  5.4
2  9.5
```

Comment: Is there a way to rename the column?

Comment: @stacky You can do `df = pd.DataFrame(sample_list, columns=[2]).rename(columns={2: "New Column"})` for example.